# Horizontal scrolling on nedit with trackpad under XQuartz - MacOS Catalina

Tags: trackpad, text-editor, macos, x11, xquartz

I use sometimes the nedit editor with XQuartz on my MacBook pro. Everything works fine except the fact that I can't do horizontal scrolling with trackpad of the content of the file opened with nedit.

This is relatively frustrating, mostly when lines are long, I am obliged to scroll using the horizontal scroll bar of nedit (at the bottom of the window).

So I am wondering if there is a way to do horizontal scrolling directly wwith trackpad. I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.1.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use nedit and I can't scroll horizontally with my mouse. I have to manually move the scroll by clicking in the scroll bar at bottom of page. I don't have a trackpad to test with. If I place the cursor on a line and then click, hold and move the cursor to the right, then the page will scroll left.